# How to create a reusable module in Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework, code-reuse

For various reasons, in my latest project I need to provide an almost identical view/feature both in the admin back end, as well as in the front end. What is the best way to do this?

Example of what i need:

There exists a table, with some crud controls. I need to show this table in the frontend without the controls, and in the backend with these controls. The main thing is, that they have to look alike, and when I make a visual change in one, the other should follow suit. Therefore it sounds logical, to have but one, and then reuse it, while passing on parameters to that determine whether the controls are shown.

But how do I do this in Zend Framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just create a view partial for the table which relies on a parameter to show / hide controls.

```
<?php echo $this->partial('my-table.phtml', 'module-name', array(
    'showControls' => true
)) ?>
```

Using the three argument version of the partial helper lets you keep the partial script in one particular module where you can reference it from anywhere else.

Comment: Now this is quite good. I was thinking it would be more difficult. I'll give it a try. Thanks!